# %0d%0a getting added behind the URL of a href attribute in an <a> tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

In a helper plugin for WooCommerce for WordPress, I'm trying to create a custom message to be sent to a buyer.

I don't know why in all the emails that are sent out, %0d%0a is getting added behind the URL in the href attribute. I have tried several different combinations and nothing is working.

This is what I'm trying to do:

`echo "<a href='$cl'> Please click here to redeem the coupon</a>";`

But because %0d%0a is being added at the back of it the URL doesn't work properly for coupon codes.

This is what the URL looks like afterwards:

https://www.example.com/product-1/?couponCode=TDXGUA9G&utm_source=test&utm_medium=testt&utm_campaign=test&aff_code=TSJU89XYZ%0d%0a

The only thing that doesn't add %0d%0a is this:

```
 echo $cl;
```

But I want to be able to use the `<a>` tag so that the buyer doesn't have to click on a long URL link.

Comment: Try to switch the quotation marks. href needs double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: I have tried that combination too. I read in stackoverflow that I can use single quotes for it so I tried that too.

Comment: There are several other things to check: does $cl contain the characters %0d%0a? how is $cl created? Then check if this is a browser/email client problem. You can do that by writing the output to a file and analyzing the exact string. and finally check the language settings in your editor (utf-8?).

Comment: Please mention what is in $cl. Have you already included the <a> tag in $cl?

Comment: `%0d%0a` is a line break. You just don't see it when you use `echo` because it isn't displayed. It is still there. Clean up your variable, use `trim()` if necessary.

Comment: $cl contained a URL that was saved in a MySQL database. The URL was obtained from .CSV file. I believe that %0d%0a got added to it when the .CSV file was created. 

trim() definitely fixed the issue by removing those characters. I had tried using trim before and it didn't work. I think I must have used it incorrectly. But when I tried it in a different way then it worked. I'm a noob, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<a href='" . $cl . "'> Please click here to redeem the coupon</a>";
```

If you still have the issue, check how `$cl` was created.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate all the responses. But I just want to post the code that finally worked for me after 7 hours of work. I understand that it looks silly but this is the best I could do for now. Here's what worked for me:

```
    ?>
    <a href='<?php echo trim($cl); ?>'> <span color="#557da1">Click here to take <?php echo ' '.$_product_name.'</span></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue, but I'm using ASP.NET. All I did was delete the single quote and type it again. Now it works.

```
<asp:HyperLink ... NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
```

There were possibly some extra invisible characters which needed to be deleted.